# MAKE CREDENTIAL request is partially received

Tags: android, android-authenticator, webauthn, cbor, fido

I can able to send GET_INFO to the webauthn.io . After that, I can able to read MAKE_CREDENTIAL request partially. Total MAKE_CREDENTIAL data length is 400+. But I am getting just 90+ bytes. I am not getting entire request for MAKE_CREDENTIAL.

The request I have received is

[-125, **1, 95**, 1, -91, 1, 88, 32, 75, 1, 9, -33, -61, -39, 69, -54, -3, 113, -4, -77, 29, 83, 121, 14, -83, -123, 70, -121, -15, -106, -17, 121, 107, -118, -7, 32, -44, -74, 71, 20, 2, -94, 98, 105, 100, 107, 119, 101, 98, 97, 117, 116, 104, 110, 46, 105, 111, 100, 110, 97, 109, 101, 107, 119, 101, 98, 97, 117, 116, 104, 110, 46, 105, 111, 3, -93, 98, 105, 100, 74, -44, -98, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 110, 97, 109, 101, 100, 117, 115, 101]

As per length data total bytes should be 405. But I am receiving just 94 bytes. I debugged and analysed the code, I couldn't able to figure out the issue.

Please help me to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this [spec](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-id-20180227/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-id-20180227.html#ble-framing-fragmentation)

When WebAuthn reads Control Point Length characteristic, you should return MTU - 3 bytes. Later, whenever WebAuthn wants to send data to authenticator, WebAuthn will consider to split the data to many chunks which its length will be equal to or less than MTU - 1. The frame you received is just the first frame. There will be many more frames after that, you should handle it.

Note:

3 in MTU - 3 is bytes: MSG byte, HLEN byte, LLEN byte

1 in MTU - 1 is serial number of each packet

Comment: I am good about MTU. I have done already like this. My doubt is once I received first frame of data, What I need to do? Do I need to send PING command after every frame received?

Comment: No, you don't have to send PING command at all. WebAuthn will send you not only one frame, you have to catch all the frames, then:
1. for first frame, your remove first 3 bytes
2. from the second frame onward, you remove 1 byte
3. concatenate all the chunks

Comment: Yeah.. Now I got it.. Thank you so much.